# Maximizing a function AND its derivative.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, vector-analysis, lagrange-multiplier

I am attempting to solve the following optimization problem with the following three dimensional function $D(x,y,z)$:

Find the point $(x,y,z)$ such that the function $D(x,y,z)$ is a maximum and that the gradient $\mid \nabla D(x,y,z) \mid$ around a given distance $r$ around that point is a minimum.

What is the best way to approach this problem analytically? Am looking at Hessian methods but would like to find an explicit solution as well. I am essentially trying to find a point in space such that the value of the function is maximal and the magnitude of the gradient around a specified radius is minimal.

This question is posed within the field of image processing. Specifically, we are looking to measure the value of a 2D slice of $D$ in the plane where $D$ is maximum. We want to avoid large fall-off of $D$ as well, and that is why we are looking at the gradient. If the modulation of the gradient is too large, then we will look for another plane to measure at.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is not clear.  What, exactly, are you trying to optimize?  Gradients are vectors so what does it mean to minimize one?  More importantly, if you are trying to optimize two things at once you need to explain what you are looking for.

Comment: What do you mean by minimum of the gradient? If $D$ is a scalar function, then $\nabla D$ is a vector.

Comment: Ah, my bad! Mispoke..., I meant that we are looking for the magnitude of the gradient. Will edit the question.

Comment: But...speaking roughly, local maxima occur when the magnitude of the gradient is $0$, which is certainly minimal.  So...what are you asking?  Perhaps it would help if you gave an explicit, fully worked, example of the sort of thing you want.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean when you say "the gradient ∣∇(,,)∣ around a given distance  around that point is a minimum". I'm not sure what to make of this sentence. Is there a textbook / paper that you a reading? Or perhaps an explicit form of D and what you want from it?

Comment: I think you want to compute the matrix norm of the Hessian. The intuition is to estimate the smallest Lipschitz constant of $x\mapsto \|\nabla D(x)\|$ on a ball centered at the minimum $u$. Now, the mean value theorem implies that the smallest Lipschitz of a differentiable function $f\colon [a,b]\to \Bbb R$ is $\max_{x\in [a,b]}|f'{x}|$. You can apply this argument on $t\mapsto \|\nabla D(u+tv)\|$ and dervie an inequality of the form $\|\nabla D(u+v)\|\leq C \|v\|$ where $C$ is such that  $\||\nabla^2 D(u+w)\||\leq C$ with for all $w$ with $\|w\|\leq \|v\|$.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this question (as it is currently posed) is that the gradient looks the same for all local optima.

**Claim**: If $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a local maximum, then $\nabla f(x) = 0$.

In other words, you can't really distinguish between the gradients of various local optima.

Comment: That makes sense, but further edited my question. Thank you!

Comment: There is still some ambiguity. Let me address it in the comments to your question.

Comment: Maybe something like BFGS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden%E2%80%93Fletcher%E2%80%93Goldfarb%E2%80%93Shanno_algorithm can help.